# CSVHelper issue with reading CSV to custom object

Tags: c#, csv, csvhelper

I'm trying to read a CSV file into my custom objects, but every time I get an error saying that such fields don't exist. However, they do actually exist.

Here's my code:

```
public class Order
{
    public string isin { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
}

class OrderMap : CsvClassMap<Order>
{
    [System.Obsolete("use CreateMap", true)]
    public override void CreateMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.isin).Index(0);
        Map(m => m.price).Index(1);
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"data\1\my_file.csv");
    var csv = new CsvReader(file);
    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<OrderMap>();
    var orderFlow = csv.GetRecords<Order>().ToList();
```

When I try to access certain field via `getField<string>(Index)` I get the same error for all indexes above 0. `getField<string>(0)` returns the entire row separated with `;`. What's wrong?

Comment: it would help if you included a sample of your .csv

Comment: Here is the sample file [my_file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5OkyPK6K1t-UGktOVpYS3V5Unc/view?usp=sharing). Any help is welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have not specified your delimiter as a `;`.  The default delimiter is `,`.  You need to update your configuration.  You can find additional information on the library [site](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/#configuration-delimiter).

```
csv.Configuration.Delimiter = ";";
```

Comment: After-all it's called a CSV and not a SCSV.  Just a joke, but Dmeel is right.